# How do I add a Colour and Storage Variant to a Product already present in the Database?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, sql-insert

I have the following two tables: (C# and MS Access)

```
_sSqlString = "CREATE TABLE Device("
                                                + "deviceIdNo AUTOINCREMENT,"
                                                + "brandName VARCHAR,"
                                                + "modelName VARCHAR,"
                                                + "deviceCaliber VARCHAR,"
                                                + "batterySize INT,"
                                                + "screenSize DOUBLE,"
                                                + "frontCameraMP INT,"
                                                + "rearCameraMP INT,"
                                                + "PRIMARY KEY (deviceIdNo)"
                                                + ")";

 _sSqlString = "CREATE TABLE DeviceColourStorage("
                                                + "deviceIdNo AUTOINCREMENT,"
                                                + "storageCapacity VARCHAR,"
                                                + "colourVariant VARCHAR,"
                                                + "FOREIGN KEY(deviceIdNo) REFERENCES Device(deviceIdNo)"
                                                + ")";
```

**Goal:**

Allow user to add Colour and Storage Variants to a Device already present in the Database.

**What I have tried:**

**Successfully**: Hardcoding the deviceIdNo in DeviceColourStorage Table to 1. Any time I add a new Storage Capacity or Colour Variant, it would always link it with the Device of deviceIdNo 1.

**Unsuccessfully**: Using an INSERT SELECT command to select the deviceIdNo based on brandName and modelName. In this example I have hardcoded the values Apple and iPhone 12.

storageCapacity and colourVariant are variables passed in from another section of code where the user would input the values. (i.e 64 and Red)

```
string _sSqlString = "INSERT INTO DeviceColourStorage (deviceIdNo, storageCapacity, colourVariant)" + " Values((SELECT deviceIdNo FROM Device WHERE brandName = 'Apple', modelName='iPhone 12') , '" + storageCapacity + "', '" + colourVariant + "')";
```

This does not populate the fields, indicating an error of some description but I am unsure what this may be, or if there is an alternative way of resolving it.

[User Interface used by User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sSkF.png)

[MS Access Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smwnD.png)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You don't combine `VALUES` and `SELECT` in the same `INSERT` statement. It's either `INSERT INTO <table> VALUES (value, list, here);` OR `INSERT INTO <table> <select statement here>;`.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the query as an `insert ... select` statement:

```
INSERT INTO DeviceColourStorage (deviceIdNo, storageCapacity, colourVariant)
SELECT deviceIdNo, @storageCapacity, @colourVariant 
FROM Device 
WHERE brandName = @brandName AND modelName= @modelName
```

The variables starting with `@` represent the paramters to the query.

Comment: Thank you so much! This in conjunction with Alberts comment got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Your child table create is messed up.

Your child table should have a PK. (don't know why it does not????).

Furthermore, you are setting the column in the child table as a auto increment. That means that the database will shove in a incrementing number. BUT YOU WANT to set that value as the Foreign Key key back to the parent table.

Each table: make sure they each have a PK.

A plane jane standard long number column is ALWAYS used to relate back up to the parent table - it can NOT be a auto number since YOUR CODE has to set what row in the parent table this belongs two.

You have this :

[image]

First your child table has no PK - bad bad!

Worse above can't work. Your FK in the child table can't autoincrement - since it would have to by some magic act KNOW which parent record in device that it belongs to. And being a autoincrement, then the system will choose the value - not you!

You need this setup:

[image]

Hence your child table create statement needs to be this:

```
CREATE TABLE DeviceColourStorage
(
ID AUTOINCREMENT,
deviceIdNo LONG,
storageCapacity VARCHAR,colourVariant VARCHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY(deviceIdNo) REFERENCES Device(deviceIdNo)
)
```

So the FK is never a auto increment. You create a plane jane LONG number field. This field is the field THAT YOUR code sets to determine what parent record it belongs to.

So you REALLY need and want to have a PK for each table (bad bad you do not!).
and a FK can't be some automatic increment, since that means the system will choose some out of the blue next number for that column, not YOUR code that has to set that correct foreign key value in code - and thus allow you to set/choose what record this child row belongs to.

Comment: Thank you so much! This in conjunction with GMB's comment got it sorted!